# is Databricks access connector trusted resource in Azure?

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-data-lake, azure-managed-identity, databricks-unity-catalog

I'm trying to set up the external location for the unity catalog. it was able to connect to storage while trying to test a connection in which storage access is limited to selected vnets and ips. but I'm getting a 403 error while accessing the storage from the notebook even adding the blob contributor access to managed identity. Did I miss anything?

my assumption is since I added a connector to the trusted resources it will bypass the network rules.

Answer (score 0):

### Databricks throwing 403 error

The main reason for 403 error is related to authorization issues for accessing azure storage account to avoid access related issues Assign the application to a role, make sure to assign the Storage Blob Data Contributor role to the service principal.

> You need to have only (Storage Blob Data Contributor) Role specified on your storage for your service principal. To assign Storage Blob Data Contributor roles using portal  [follow this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal).

- I have created **demt1** storage account for demo, open Access controls -> Role assignment

![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewpPh.png

- Under Role assignment select **Storage Blob Data Contributor** created initially
  [image]
- To check if the role is assigned open Access control -> Check Access -> Check access
  and search for databricks

[image]

[image]

- Under Current assignments there will be assigned role

[image]

- Open databricks account and try to access storage by mounting an existing container

[image]

Additional Settings

[image]

Comment: I have given Blob Contrinuter role on the storage account to the Managed Identity(Databricks Access connector). still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the Databricks' workspace managed identity as a Storage Blob Data Contributor.

[IAM for Databricks Managed Identity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rl6Zf.png)

You'll also want to add the relevant IAM conditional access, such as Read / Write permissions.

[Conditional Access for Managed Identity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7XQd.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).